# Switch JdbcTemplate during integration test

Tags: java, spring, junit, integration-testing

When doing a integration test

```
@Component
public class BalanceDb {
    
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private static String TABLE = Tables.BALANCE;

    public boolean insert(Balance balance) {
        String query = "INSERT INTO %s (card_id, balance) VALUES (uuid(?), ?)";
        String sql = DatabaseHelper.addTableToQuery(TABLE, query);
        int result = jdbcTemplate.update(sql, balance.getCardId(), balance.getBalance());
        return result == 1;
    }
}
```

this is my db class, i dont want to work on the db hooked with this jdbcTemplate
i want to switch to a in memory database, but when i do this

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class BalanceDbTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("testJdbcTemplate")
    private JdbcTemplate testJdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private BalanceDb balanceDb;
    
    @Test
    void testInsert() {

        Balance balance = new Balance();
        balance.setCardId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        balance.setBalance(1000);

        assertEquals(0, JdbcTestUtils.countRowsInTable(testJdbcTemplate, "balance"));
        balanceDb.insert(balance);
        assertEquals(1, JdbcTestUtils.countRowsInTable(testJdbcTemplate, "balance"));

    }
}
```

when i do a call to balanceDb.insert(), it still uses the production database
i want it to switch to in memory database

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    private String RDS_HOSTNAME = Env.get("RDS_HOSTNAME");
    private String RDS_PORT = Env.get("RDS_PORT");
    private String RDS_DB_NAME = Env.get("RDS_DB_NAME");
    private String RDS_USERNAME = Env.get("RDS_USERNAME");
    private String RDS_PASSWORD = Env.get("RDS_PASSWORD");
    private String DRIVER_CLASS_NAME = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    private String DRIVER = "postgresql";
    private String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:" + DRIVER + "://" + RDS_HOSTNAME + ":" + RDS_PORT + "/" + RDS_DB_NAME;

    @Bean("cardDataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        // "jdbc:driver://hostname:port/dbName?user=userName&password=password";
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(DRIVER_CLASS_NAME);
        dataSource.setUrl(JDBC_URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(RDS_USERNAME);
        dataSource.setPassword(RDS_PASSWORD);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "jdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate1(@Qualifier("cardDataSource") DataSource ds) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }

}
```

.

```
@Configuration
public class TestDataSourceConfig {

    // private final String RDS_DB_NAME = "testdb";
    private final String RDS_USERNAME = "sa";
    private final String RDS_PASSWORD = "";
    private final String DRIVER_CLASS_NAME = "org.h2.Driver";
    private final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb";

    @Bean("testDataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        // "jdbc:driver://hostname:port/dbName?user=userName&password=password";
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(DRIVER_CLASS_NAME);
        dataSource.setUrl(JDBC_URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(RDS_USERNAME);
        dataSource.setPassword(RDS_PASSWORD);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "testJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate3(@Qualifier("testDataSource") DataSource ds) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }

}
```

my both configs, when i do a balanceDb.insert() it is still not switching templates

Comment: There are multiple options: You should use `@Profile` instead of bean names and qualifiers, or use spring boot configuration properties with a prod and a test properties file.

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond thanks for the solution, can you please explain more in detail how to use `@ActiveProfile` in this case.

I am not so good with the testing, would be great if you can help me through this